# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'simplewebtool/us-central1/ssr' when deploying Angular Universal SSR app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I circumvented all prior issues to get SSR rendering working properly with my Angular Universal app, however upon attempting a local build before deploying to production with both Firebase Hosting and now Cloud Functions I ran into the below issue:

[image]

Below is my webpack.server.config.js

```js
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  externals: [
    /^firebase/
    //'./dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
  ],
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'app',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /polyfills-.*\.js/,
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

package.json (inside the functions folder)

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "node cp-angular && tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Current firebase configuration (firebase.json):

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

cp-angular.js:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.copy('../dist', './dist').then(() => {
    // We should remove the original "index.html" since Firebase will use it when SSR is enabled (instead of calling SSR functions),
    // and because of that, SSR won't work for the initial page.
    fs.remove('../dist/browser/index.html').catch(e => console.error('REMOVE ERROR: ', e));
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('COPY ERROR: ', err)
});
```

Comment: are u getting the same error when deploying?